# Interactive python variables in a script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've a python script which loads interactive python with many libraries. I can access the library objects and their attributes from that interactive python window, which it loads. I want to read a list of variables from the library. So, thought to put them in a function and call them all at once. I wrote a script with one function loaded with the commands which reads all the variables. Now, when I import the script in the same interactive python shell and call the function. I'm getting "NameError". Any inputs in achieving this, will be much appreciated

Below is the sample output
[image: Interactive python shell]
test_script.py

```
def print_vals():
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

Comment: Please show us a [mcve] that produces some examples.

Answer (score 0):

The variables a and b need to be passed inside the function

```
a=10
b=20
def print_vals(a, b):
    print(a)
    print(b)
print_vals(a,b)
10
20
```